# SQL logic for multiple column uniqueness

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given

```
CREATE TABLE table (a TEXT, b TEXT, c TEXT UNIQUE (a, b) );
```

does this constraint mean `a OR b` must be unique or `a AND b`?

Comment: the second   a AND b .. and index is evaluated  (significat)  left to righ ..permutation between  column si not possible in index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your table definition :

```
CREATE TABLE table (a TEXT, b TEXT, c TEXT UNIQUE (a, b) );
```

Your table definition has composite unique key `UNIQUE (a, b)` which means `a and b` should not be duplicate or you can also say *unique pair* of `a and b`. However, `NULL` can be ignore.

Below sample data illustrate this :

```
 a    b   c (doesnt matter)
 -----------
'a'  'b' --- valid
'a'  'b' --- will throw error
'b'  'a' --- valid
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was hoping/thinking but I couldn't find it explicitly stated.

Answer (score 2):

`A and B`. The following combinations are valid:

```
A   B
--- ---
abc def
abc ghi -- 'abc' again, but with different B column
cde ghi -- 'ghi' again, but with different A column
```

But you cannot add again:

```
abc def
```